# Energy conservation in a system of two bodies

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, projectile, string

[image]

I have no idea why my previous post was marked as a homework question where the solution was clearly visible. I was asking to clear a concept of mine regarding system of bodies.

However,i will keep things to the point this time. The picture shows two bodies attached to a massless rod in a vertical plane and they can rotate about the topmost point. Suppose we give a velocity $v$ to the lower mass.When conserving energies, why is that the *total* potential and kinetic energies of the two bodies conserved and not individually? Like the equation was
$m_2gr+\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2=$ that of the final. Why couldn't we just equate $m_2gr+\frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2$ or the same with $m_1$? If we consider *any one of the masses and earth* as the system and then conserve energy? No external force us acting on that system. Moreover, in the equation stated above,shouldn't there be a gravitational potential energy equal to $-\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r}$ included as well since there are two masses? Kindly clear my misconception. I don't get why the energy of the system of the two bodies and earth remain conserved but when considering individual masses, the energy doesn't remain conserved.

Comment: Can we assume the "top most point" is fixed to some structure?

Comment: Previous post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/718652/2451

Comment: @BobD yes,that point is fixed and the bodies are rotating about that point.

Comment: Another point. Your original post had the masses connected to each other and to the top support by massless rods. Now you are saying they are  ropes.  Since ropes are not rigid the two masses will not move together like with rigid rods

Comment: @BobD i have edited it to a massless rod now,Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Total mechanical energy (KE+PE) of a system is conserved if the sum of external forces acting on the system is zero. Consider the following systems:

1. $m_1$ plus Earth
2. $m_2$ plus Earth
3. $m_1$ + $m_2$ + Earth

System (3) can be considered isolated since the force of gravity and the forces each mass exerts on the other are internal to the system. Thus for system (3) mechanical energy is conserved.

Systems (1) and (2) are not isolated. $m_2$ is an external force on system (1) and $m_1$ is and external force acting on system (2). Thus mechanical energy is not conserved for systems (1) and (2).

$m_1$  and $m_2$ alone are not isolated systems since they are each acted upon by the other and by the force of gravity.

Finally, the gravitational force between the two masses (and the associated potential energy) is an internal force of system (3) . In any event, the potential energy between, say, two 1 kg masses separated by 1 meter is on the order of 10$^{-10}$ Joule .

> It seems that the only reason we are conserving energy as a whole is
> due to the tension force.

Energy as a whole is always conserved when you consider both the defined "system" and its "surroundings", which together constitute the "universe".

The reason we are conserving energy in system (3) is because no net work is being done on/by the system with respect to its surroundings. When net work is done by or on a system energy is added to or removed from the system with respect to its surroundings.

> I had decided that whenever I see more than one body, I will have to
> conserve the total energy instead of considering the energy of
> individual bodies.

It’s not how many bodies are involved. It’s whether or not they interact.  Suppose $m_1$ and $m_2$ in systems (1) and (2) above were not connected to each other by a rod. If the gravitational attraction between them is negligible (as in my example above) and they do not otherwise interact, then energy is conserved in each system.

> So, that means if I just have some bodies spread, with no connection
> between them, I can equate the initial and final energy of the
> individual bodies instead of considering as a whole, right?

Correct. That’s what I just said.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying,a silly question,could you please  tell me how $m_2$ is an external force to system $1$ or $m_1$ an external system to system $2$? I mean what force do they apply on the system? Do you mean the weight $m_2g$ or $m_1g$. If yes,then could you please tell me how?

Comment: Another question if you don't mind, even if we include the Gravitational PE, wouldn't the two cancel out?Since it is counted once in the initial energy and will be counted again in the final energy and the energy will remain the same,so the two terms will just cancel out on both sides of the equation,won't they?

Comment: @madness    The tension in the bar connecting the two masses is an external force on sytems 1 and 2 but it is an internal force on system 3.. Regarding Gravitational PE between the masses, since the separation is fixed it doesn't change when the masses move, i.e., it is constant

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that the only reason we are conserving energy as a whole is due to the tension force. I had decided that whenever I see more than one body,i will have to conserve the total energy instead of considering the energy of individual bodies. So,that means if i just have some bodies spread,with no connection between them,i can equate the initial and final energy of the individual bodies instead of considering as a whole, right?

Comment: @madness Rather than attempt to respond in comments, I have updated my answer to respond. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am extremely sorry for bothering you again. We know the work-energy theorem is always valid(even for a single particle). If we consider WE theorem for m1, work done by gravity is $−mg(4r)$. Work done by the tension force is 0 since angle between tension and velocity is $90$. And change in $KE$ is $−\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2$,so we get $mg(4r)=\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2$. But as we all have been pointing out that this equation isn't true. It differs from the equation where we equate the energy of the whole system. How is WE theorem failing in this case?

Comment: @madness Tell me, precisely, what the work energy theorem says.

Comment: ,as it is written in books,the work done by all the forces on a body is equal to the change in kinetic energy. I searched up in the internet and found that this theorem is always valid.

Comment: @madness It is very important to include the work “net” before “work”.  In any case, the work energy theorem is not "failing" in this example. From the original post we know that the initial kinetic energy of the bottom mass alone is greater than the negative work done by gravity to bring it to rest at the top. To satisfy the work energy theorem that means that some external force is acting on the bottom mass doing work on it. That external work is done by the upper mass "pulling up" the bottom mass.

Comment: Now I know you are thinking the tension in the rod does no work. That is true if the only thing is the massless rod between the bottom mass and the upper support (a simple pendulum). But that is not the case here. There is a mass in between. The inertial force of that upper mass pulls up on the lower mass doing work.

Comment: Thank you very much for bearing with me. Is there any way to calculate that work? I thought it would be $$\int T\mathrm{d}r \cos \theta$$ and since $\theta=90^{\circ}$,the work done will be $0$. It doesn't seem to be the case as you said. Could you kindly tell how to calculate the work done by the tension force?

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in Chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137901/discussion-between-bob-d-and-madness).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, only the total energy of an isolated system is conserved.
You write

> No external force us acting on that system.

meaning the system of earth and one of the masses... But it is not true: the two bodies do interact with each other via a mechanical force - they pull the rope between them! Hence, Earth+$m_1$ is not an isolated system.

The contribution $- G m_1 m_2 /r$ to gravitational potential energy is simply so small that you can neglect it - for sure you don't expect to feel the gravitational attraction between two things hanging on a rope.

Comment: Thanks for replying. One thing is even if we include the Gravitational PE, wouldn't the two cancel out?Since it is counted once in the initial energy and will be counted again in the final energy and the energy will remain the same,so the two terms will just cancel out on both sides of the equation,won't they?

Comment: As you said in your first line,energy of a isolated system is conserved,how do we know which system is isolated?

Answer (score 0):

You choose the system.
Once this is done then internal and external forces need to be identified.
An internal force will always have a Newton's third law pair and an external force will not have a Newton third law pair.

**System** - masses $m_1$ alone.
The mass $m_1$ has no internal (Newton third law pair) forces acting and two external forces:
*force on mass $m_1$ due to the massless rod* and
*force on mass $m_1$ due to the gravitational attraction of the Earth*.
The kinetic energy of the system is not conserved.

**System** - masses $m_1,\, m_2$ alone.
Masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ act on each other via the massless rod so there are internal (Newton third law pair) forces:
*force on mass $m_1$ due to rod and force on rod due to mass $m_1$* and
*force on mass $m_2$ due to rod and force on rod due to mass $m_2$*
and external forces:
*gravitational force due to Earth on mass $m_1$* and
*gravitational force due to Earth on mass $m_2$*,
thus the mechanical energy of the system is not conserved.

**System** - masses $m_1,\, m_2$ and Earth.
Masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ act on each other via the massless rod and the masses and the Earth interact via the gravitational force so there are internal (Newton third law pair) forces:
*force on mass $m_1$ due to rod and force on rod due to mass $m_1$*,
*force on mass $m_2$ due to rod and force on rod due to mass $m_2$*,
*gravitational force due to Earth on mass $m_1$ and gravitational force due to mass $m_1$ on Earth* and
*gravitational force due to Earth on mass $m_2$* and *gravitational force due to mass $m_2$ on Earth*,
As here are no external forces present, the mechanical energy of the system is conserved.

In general you need to identify external forces and torques acting on the system of your choice.
One other thing to note is that you cannot use the concept of gravitational potential energy unless you have a system with at least two masses present.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying,could you please answer this silly question of mine? What do we mean by *force on $m_1$ or $m_2$ due to massless rod*? I mean what kind of force us this? Any kind of tension force?Sorry for being dumb.